# How can I compare a string (of a given format) to current date?

Tags: android, date, format

I want to compare a date string (that I get form a viewHolder) with this format "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm" to current date and time but I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`. This is how I tried:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateAndTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ROOT);
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
String currentDateAndTime = dateAndTimeFormat.format(localDate.toString());

if(viewHolder.time.getText().toString().equals(currentDateAndTime)){
            //irrelevant
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleDataFormat.format(...)` takes a Date object as its [first parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You're passing in a String because you're calling `toString()` on it. Try this:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateAndTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ROOT);
String currentDateAndTime = dateAndTimeFormat.format(new Date());

if (viewHolder.time.getText().toString().equals(currentDateAndTime)) {
  //irrelevant
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I need **current date**, and for that I have to use LocalDate.now(), which is not accepted by SimpleDateFormat.format()

Comment: @SebastianMocanu `new Date()` gives you the current date

Comment: When the question is about the modern `LocalDate`, I disagree to suggest the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Both of those classes are poorly designed and long outdated. No one should want to take this step backward.

Answer (score 0):

Go all-in on java.time, the modern Java dat and time API.

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateAndTimeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ROOT);
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String currentDateAndTime = zdt.format(dateAndTimeFormat);

    System.out.println(currentDateAndTime);
```

When I ran the code just now using Pacific/Honolulu time zone as my default, the output was:

> 01-05-2020 08:47

### What went wrong in your code?

Two things were wrong:

1. A `LocalDate` is just a date without time of day, so there is no way you can format it into a string that includes hour of day and minute. Instead use `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`.
2. It’s good to use `LocalDate` or another class from java.time, the modern Java date and time API. The modern classes and the outdated `SimpleDateFormat` don’t work together. To format a date and/or time object from java.time you need to use the modern `DateTimeFormatter` class. Which is good because `SimpleDateFormat` is a notoriously troublesome class that you should not want to use under any circumstances. What tends to fool us is that your code actually compiled, which gives the impression that it should work. It was never meant to. `SimpleDateFormat` inherits the `format(Object)` method from `Format`, a general superclass for formatting many kinds of objects, which is why the argument is declared to be `Object`, not `Date` (another outdated class).

Comment: One upvote, one downvote. Curious. I didn't think that what I said was so controversial. Any explanation would be welcome.